# How to use NAudio component for playback of mp3 files on a Blazor Web Assembly client?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, html5-audio, naudio

Been going through the NAudio documentation and I haven't been able to determine which playback component should be used to playback mp3 files on a Blazor WASM client. MediaFoundaitionReader seems to require Windows OS (Windows Audio Session API WASAPI) and if I use the streaming component then I am not playing the audio from the WASM client.

The objective is create an Blazor WASM client application that can be used on any device to play an mp3 files.

How do I use an NAudio component playback of an mp3 file on a Blazor Web Assembly client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution with NAudio, but I did realize I was making this too complicated. Web browsers have media playback built into them.

I created this [Blazor component](https://github.com/tysongibby/BlazorWebAudioDemo) using the HTML5 `<audio>` element that does exactly what I need.

```
<audio id="audioCtrl" src="@AudioFilePath" controls="@ShowControls" loop="@Loop" controlsList="@controlList" >@NotSupported</audio>
<br />
<btn id="playBtn" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="TogglePlay">@playBtnText</btn>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? AudioFilePath { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public bool Loop { get; set; } = false;
    [Parameter]
    public bool AllowDownload { get; set; } = false;
    [Parameter]
    public bool AllowPlaybackRate { get; set; } = true;
    [Parameter]
    public bool ShowControls { get; set; } = true;
    [Parameter]
    public string NotSupported { get; set; } = "Your browser does not support HTML 5 media or it does not support this audio file type.";

    private string controlList = string.Empty;

    private bool play = true;
    private string playBtnText = "Play";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        if (!AllowDownload)
        {
            controlList = controlList + "nodownload ";
        }
        if (!AllowPlaybackRate)
        {
            controlList = controlList + "noplaybackrate ";
        }
    }

    // Toggle to pause if play is true, else toggle to play
    private void TogglePlay()
    {        
        if (play)
        {
            //toggle to pause
            play = false;
            playBtnText = "Pause";            
        }
        else 
        {
            //toggle to play
            play = true;
            playBtnText = "Play";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .mp3 used to be proprietary, and you had to add fallbacks in the markup.  But I think that ended about 8 years ago (ish)