# Can't figure out how to grab files for use in NAudio in a Blazor setup

Tags: c#, blazor, backend, naudio

For the last several days I have been struggling with the very starting points of a web-app I've been trying to build.

The intention is for it to grab audio files that are already on the server, do some stuff to them (concatenating, mixing, etcetera) based on the user's requirements, and post an output.mp3 file that the user can then download.

However, it's the first part that I've been struggling with. No matter what I do, I just can't figure out how to grab a .wav or any other audio format file from the server.

I have tried grabbing it via an `Http.GetAsyncStream("path/to/file.wav");` call, but that gets me stuck with a garbage stream data I can't convert into anything else, because NAudio is missing mfplat.dll on the Github Pages server.

I have tried other `Http GetAsync` methods, but that left me with even less to work with.

I have tried just trying to read the file straight up via `var first = new AudioFileReader("path/to/file.wav");` and that consistently errors out with `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: IO_PathNotFound_Path, /sounds/testing/switch.wav`, even though it *absolutely* is in the root folder of the server, and the javascript side of Blazor can actually read it.

After several days of Googling and trying to figure it out myself, I'm stuck. I'm clearly missing something baseline to how Blazor functions, but I have no idea what.

Any help? Please?

EDIT:
As requested, here are a few of my attempts.

```
public void ConcatAudio()
{
    audioTest = new WaveFileReader("sounds/testing/switch.wav");
}
```

This was what I started with. I expected this to set the audioTest variable to the grabbed .wav file, for future use with NAudio.

Instead it error out with an `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: IO_PathNotFound_Path, /sounds/testing/switch.wav` error.

I also tried several variants of this.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    audioTest = (WaveFormatConversionStream) await Http.GetStreamAsync("sounds/testing/switch.wav");
}
```

I expect it to do the same, give me a variable with the .wav file in it for future use with NAudio.

These either error out with an invalid cast error, or, as the only one where I *somewhat* succeeded, gave me a `System.IO.Stream` that I couldn't really do anything with, as I needed it specifically in a format that NAudio would accept.

If required, here's a link to the full code repo, though 99% of it is the starting Blazor project.
https://github.com/DestinyPlayer/Project-Biovocoder

Comment: Is the problem related to audio files or does the download not work at all ?

Comment: It's specifically an issue with audio files. I can tell how to grab JSON files and pure data, the issue is specifically with me being stuck when it comes to trying to figure out how to make the serverside C# code read serverside audio files.

Comment: Please post your actual code that is not working with a discription of what the current problem/error is and what is the desired result.

Comment: Added. When I wrote this I thought I was being concise enough but apparently I shouldn't write coding help requests while insomniac >>

Comment: You are using blazor webassembly in the project. I am not sure if naudio can be used in wasm. Maybe this might interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74831630/how-to-use-naudio-component-for-playback-of-mp3-files-on-a-blazor-web-assembly-c

Comment: The main issue for me is that the functionality that I need at the end is not playback, it's taking a sentence, compositing a sound per letter/letter combination into a single track and then letting the user download it. If it was just playback, I could just do it in Javascript.

Comment: Apologies for being scatterbrained like this but I've been banging my head against this wall so much it actually gave me insomnia >>

Comment: Ok I have a vert very crude suggestion: try using `wwwroot/sounds/testing/switch.wav`. The thing is when you do `sounds/testing...` it searches for a sounds folder at the ProjectLevel which doesnt exit since its in the root level

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that, doesn't work, the issue is that the code runs on the `gh-pages` branch rather than the `main` branch and so wwroot just plain doesn't exist there.

Comment: @SystemSearcher hmm are you sure you cant do anything with the System.IO.Stream? Im pretty sure that you can make a WaveStream out of that since a Stream can be used as the parameter for a WaveFileReader.

Comment: Ok can Blazor even "play" NAudio files? The thing is Im doing some testing and even when the the File is being read correctly and I have the approproaye AudioFileReader I just cant play it with the audio component, since src expects well a path

Comment: I've been *trying* to do what you're saying, just sending a System.IO.Stream into WaveFileReader, but it errored out on me.

Comment: As for playing NAudio files... I don't really need to PLAY the files. I just need to concatenate a bunch of audio files into one based on a string and save them onto the server so that they can then be downloaded by the user. It's just that NAudio was the only library I've managed to dig up that offers a solution to that.

Comment: @SystemSearcher yeah I took a look and a issue arises from the Stream you get from the Http.GetStreamAsync. Its Length Attribute isnt initialized and then throws errors. And if this is just about getting the objects I think I found a way to trick the system

Answer (score 0):

I will be honest with you this isnt all that pretty and I dont know if the AudioFileReader object we get out of it is going to be "undamaged". If there still are issues with this id recomend taking a look at some source code of NAudio and to try to "recosntruct" some of the constructors that are giving you an issue, like are are doing with AudioFileReader.

```
@code{
    public AudioFileReader? audioTest;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //this is to get around getting a HttpResponseStream without length
        var cont = await Http.GetAsync("sounds/testing/switch.wav");
        var firstStream = await cont.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        audioTest = Extensions.GetAudioFileReaderFromStream(firstStream, ".wav");

    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

This is not my own Idea the credit belongs to the GithubUser: https://github.com/EitanRa
who posted a really good solution in this issue: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/issues/826

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static AudioFileReader? GetAudioFileReaderFromStream(Stream stream, string fileExt)
    {
        try
        {
            AudioFileReader reader = (AudioFileReader)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(AudioFileReader));

            Type type = reader.GetType();
            type.GetField("lockObject", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(reader, new object());
            var readerStream = GetWaveStream(stream, fileExt);
            type.GetField("readerStream", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(reader, readerStream);
            var sbps = readerStream.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8 * readerStream.WaveFormat.Channels;
            type.GetField("sourceBytesPerSample", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(reader, sbps);
            var sampleChannel = new SampleChannel(readerStream, forceStereo: false);
            type.GetField("sampleChannel", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(reader, sampleChannel);
            var dbps = 4 * sampleChannel.WaveFormat.Channels;
            type.GetField("destBytesPerSample", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(reader, dbps);
            var std = dbps * (readerStream.Length / sbps);
            type.GetField("length", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(reader, std);

            return reader;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static WaveStream GetWaveStream(Stream stream, string fileExt)
    {
        WaveStream readerStream = null;
        if (fileExt.Equals(".wav", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            readerStream = new WaveFileReader(stream);
            if (readerStream.WaveFormat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm && readerStream.WaveFormat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.IeeeFloat)
            {
                readerStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(readerStream);
                readerStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(readerStream);
            }
        }
        else if (fileExt.Equals(".mp3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6)
            {
                readerStream = new Mp3FileReader(stream);
            }
            else
            {
                readerStream = new StreamMediaFoundationReader(stream);
            }
        }
        else if (fileExt.Equals(".aiff", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || fileExt.Equals(".aif", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            readerStream = new AiffFileReader(stream);
        }
        else
        {
            readerStream = new StreamMediaFoundationReader(stream);
        }
        return readerStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. This seems to function to actually grab the file, but then I run into a failure of being able to actually save the file in any way.

Comment: Specifically, I tried this: ```public void ConcatAudio()
 {
  var playlist = new ConcatenatingSampleProvider(new[] {audioTest, audioTest, audioTest});
  WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16("playlist.wav", playlist);

  CheckFile = true;
 }``` and it then errors out with `HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource https://localhost:7100/playlist.wav failed.`

Comment: At this point I'm half convinced that Blazor just doesn't support what I seek to try and do with it and I'd be better off just building it as a separate application, hosting it on the server and then using Javascript in order to communicate with it and run it via command line or some other trick like that >>

Comment: @SystemSearcher yeah probably. NAudio just seems like it isnt made for it. But Ill take a look at your issue

Comment: @SystemSearcher ok status update: Im able to turn the sample into a stream/content to upload, but i do not quite know how to create the file where we need it, since httpclient post wont work without an API

Comment: @SystemSearcher Do you need the file to be created and stored in the sample-data folder, or do you just need to download the file to the user?

Comment: I'd appreciate the ability to store it on the server first before being downloaded, so that the user could preview it by playing it via `<audio></audio>` in the HTML part.

Comment: @SystemSearcher well then its official: Youll need to have an API since WASM (for security reasons) really really dosnt like to create files this way. But for now I think the best way to go if Im wrong is to try and manage to create a new json file in the sample-data wolder. If that works then the soundfile should work as well